# Rolling average trendline on stacked barchart in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, moving-average

I am trying to copy the nytimes covid case barplot, but I want to make it a stacked barplot. My problem is that the 7 day rolling average trendline gets messed up by my stacking variable, "states". Of course, this visualization isn't ideal but now that I can't figure it out it is driving me crazy. If you don't group by state and remove "color=states" it works fine as shown in the bottom picture.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

data_url <- "http://covidtracking.com/api/states/daily.csv"
corona <- read_csv(data_url)
corona <- corona %>% 
  mutate(date=lubridate::parse_date_time(date, "ymd"))

total<-corona %>%
  group_by(date,state)%>%
summarise_at(vars(positiveIncrease),sum)%>%mutate(seven_avg= rollmean(positiveIncrease, 7,
                             align="left", 
                             fill=0))
  ggplot(total,aes(x=date,
             y=positiveIncrease,fill=state)) +
  geom_col()+
  geom_line(aes(y = seven_avg), 
            color = "red", 
            size = .75)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what your desired output is here. Perhaps you could more clearly demonstrate the problem with a smaller, sample dataset?

Comment: Okay, I hope these figures help describe what I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `geom_line` will not aggregate your data for you. Instead you get a trend line which connects all the observations on the state level, no a line of the overall, aggregated trend.

The simple solution is to use an aggregated dataset to get the aggregated trend line:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

data_url <- "http://covidtracking.com/api/states/daily.csv"
corona <- read_csv(data_url)
corona <- corona %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::parse_date_time(date, "ymd"))

total <- corona %>%
  group_by(date, state) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(positiveIncrease), sum) %>%
  mutate(seven_avg = rollmean(positiveIncrease, 7,
    align = "left",
    fill = 0
  ))

overall <- total %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(positiveIncrease), sum) %>%
  mutate(seven_avg = rollmean(positiveIncrease, 7,
                              align = "left",
                              fill = 0
  ))

ggplot(total, aes(
  x = date,
  y = positiveIncrease
)) +
  geom_col(aes(color = state)) +
  geom_line(data = overall, aes(y = seven_avg),
    color = "red",
    size = .75,
  )
```

[image]

Comment: You are welcome. BTW: Another option without the need of a second dataset would be to make use of `stat_summary(aes(y = seven_avg), fun = "sum", geom = "line", color = "red", size = .75)` which will do the aggregation for you. Note however that the trend line will be different as in that case the state trends will be simply summed up.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your desired but there are multiple issues with your current code and it hard to see without break down the chart into two graph.

1. There are 56 state in your date (ares there 56 states in US? - I thought it was 50) When you draw the `geom_line` they all at the bottom because the value and scale relative to the bar charts so it look like one red blob at the bottom but it actually combination of 56 red lines at the bottom of your graph.
2. Not sure what you want to comebine here but a daily graph for 9 months would be a lot of data to graph all 56 states on one graph. Can you come up with  specific questions you want to answer then we can come up with better ideas of how to graph the data.

Here is my code break down your original into two graph to make it easier to understand what data contains and how ggplot work.

First one is the bar graph of all states for the 1st of every month instead of every day in the dataset. As 56 state it hard to read even with the legend so I remove legend from these graph.
WOW What happened in Texas 71k cases increase on November 1st? (I manually check the data to see which state owns that high bar)

```
ggplot(data = total %>% filter(lubridate::day(date) == 1)) +
  geom_col(aes(x = date,
               y = positiveIncrease, group = state,
               color = state), position = "dodge") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Here is the line graph of `seven_avg` for 56 states

```
ggplot(data = total) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = seven_avg, group = state,
                color = state), 
            size = .75) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]